# Laravel Database migration -errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, laravel, mariadb

While migrating Database i got an error like

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `audit_portal`.`audit_designation` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint
> is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `audit_designation` add
> constraint `audit_designation_fk_department_id_foreign` foreign key
> (`fk_department_id`) references `audit_department` (`id`) on delete
> cascade)

Here is my code

Table Departments

```
class CreateAuditDepartmentTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('audit_department', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('department_name');
             $table->string('department_code');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('audit_department');
    }
}
```

Table designation

```
class CreateAuditDesignationTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('audit_designation', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('designation_name');
            $table->string('designation_code');
            $table->string('level_type');

            $table->integer('fk_department_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('fk_department_id')->references('id')->on('audit_department')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->enum('designation_status', [0, 1])->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('audit_designation');
    }

}
```

Can't create table audit_portal.audit_designation.Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: it should be `bigInteger()` as `$table->bigInteger('fk_department_id')->unsigned();` because your `audit_designation` table's `id` is **Unsigned Big Integer**

Comment: Also, check which table is migrating first. `audit_designation` has to be migrated `after audit_department` table.